# Unable to access public files in storage folder: Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I recently upgraded my API to PHP 8.2 (from 7.4) and it was working fine with Laravel 8.
I have a `Form` model which contains list of PDFs:

[image]

These PDFs are accessible via public storage like so:

`https://schedule-api.local/storage/forms/51a59440e6d874b7ed2c91882efaf80c.pdf` but now when I try to access the file, I get this:

[image]

I checked `laravel.log` - no errors,
I checked `/var/log/apache2/schedule-api-error.log` and I get this:

[image]

Other info:

- I have executed `php artisan storage:link`
- When I access these PDFs from `/var/www/html/schedule-api/storage/app/public/forms` directory using Ubuntu - it works just fine

Here's my mutator for the `file` attribute:

```
public function setFileAttribute($value): void
{
    $file = $value;

    if ($file instanceof UploadedFile && $file->isValid()) {
       $oldFile = $this->attributes['file'] ?? null;

       // Remove old file
       if (! empty($oldFile)) {
          $value = $oldFile;
          $path = "forms/{$oldFile}";

          if (Storage::disk('public')->exists($path)) {
             Storage::disk('public')->delete($path);
          }
        } else {
           $extension = $file->guessExtension();
           $value = self::randomFileName().'.'.$extension;
        }

        $file->storeAs('forms', $value, ['disk' => 'public']);
   }

   $this->attributes['file'] = $value;
}
```

Here's the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try to check the response mime type, if it's actually application/pdf

Comment: If it's apache error, then it might be related to htaccess file. Maybe it points to wrong index.php or not in a public folder.

Comment: I checked response mime type and it shows `text/html` which isn't correct.

Comment: I also checked the DocumentRoot and Directory and both pointing to the correct path.

Comment: Try to add a route which returns file with response instead of accessing directly to your file

Comment: Thanks Stewie. I will also check mime types in the apache config

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a controller method with route where you return file based on it's name. Something like this :

```
public function getMyFile(string $filename){
  $form = Form::where('file',$filename)->first();
  abort_if(!$form, 404);
  $path = storage_path('public/forms/' . $filename);
  return Response::make(file_get_contents($path), 200, [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
    'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="'.$filename.'"'
  ]);

}
```